# Why mobile phone and laptop computers’ screens are polarized?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, polarization, electronics, electrical-engineering

Why is it necessary to use either a linear or a circular polariser for mobile phone and laptop computers’ screen?

Comment: That is true for liquid crystal displays only, mind you. Look up (wiki) how LCD displays work.

Comment: @JonCuster actually, it's not quite true. Although not necessary in principle, polarizers are still practical necessity even in AMOLED screens — to reduce the amount of reflection and thus increase contrast ratio. See [this article](https://technology.ihs.com/509943/why-all-amoled-is-applying-polarizer-suppliers-of-amoled-polarizer-and-compensation-film-for-polarizer-technology-trend-of-amoled-use-polarizer) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the LCD in your device works by rotating the polarization of the backlight source in those segments of the display that are energized. To make those segments appear black, you place a polarizing filter in front of the display screen so that its polarization direction is at 90 degrees to that of the energized segment. This blocks light transmission out of the display from the energized segments.